# How to make a insert query with string as blob in delphi / interbase

Tags: string, delphi, blob, interbase

I'd like to make a query insert:

INSERT INTO A_TABLE (BLOB_FIELD) VALUES(MY_BLOB_VAL)

but I have only string values in delphi for ex:

```
procedure INSERT_BLOB_QUERY
  var
    query:String;
    my_blob_val:String;
begin
   my_blob_val := 'a blob string to be inserted';
   query := 'INSERT INTO A_TABLE (BLOB_FIELD) VALUES(' + my_blob_val + ')';
   // to execute a query....
end;
```

The problem that occours is string to blob conversion.

So how to I insert a string in a interbase blob field???

Comment: Security alert :) - look up 'SQL injection' or read http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection

Comment: @mjn: While I agree that SQL injection is something to worry about for a database accessible from the internet, what in the question makes you think okami's database is anywhere near being exposed to the internet? Most databases live a very well protected life behind firewalls, LAN access restrictions and domain security. And the code okami is showing may well be part of an otherwise very well protected n-tier solution.

Comment: Good practice is always good practice, web-connected or not: http://xkcd.com/327/

Comment: @Marjan what make you think SQL injection is not a risk when the database is accessed over a LAN (or behind a firewall) and not directly from the Internet?  What kind of protection firewalls have about SQL injection?

Comment: @jachguate: probably none, but you would have to find the database first and with proper firewalls and all ports closed that is a significant hurdle when combined with proper LAN and domain access restrictions. Unless of course you are talking about attacks from within by a company's own personnel, but then they would have other means available than resorting to SQL injection.

Comment: @Marjan They would have other means, but why left the SQL injection door wide open?... from a security point of view you have to detect and close as much as possible any hole in the system.

Comment: @jachguate: do you lock all doors **inside** your house? While it seem like a good thing to close as many holes as possible, and even paranoids have enemies, there is something called "too much of a good thing..." Even security should not be some Pavlovian knee jerk reaction, but a well thought-out and measured response to real threats.

Comment: @Marjan I really don't lock all doors inside my house, but I usually lock some doors at the office.  A good practice like using parameters, IMHO, is a good practice in general, including desktop applications, not just web. Of course this does not make the same sense if you work on a bank's software than if you work on the small shop around the corner software.

Comment: @jachguate: and your last sentence is exactly my point...

Comment: @MarjanVenema - the house doors analogy would only work if the possibility of your bedroom door suddenly looking at the street were true. Code does that; it evolves, its responsibilities change, and your function may even get exposed by a wrapper method written by somebody else on a different time or organizational level. Also, SQL injection is not the only problem here - your application may produce wrong SQL if your strings start showing up with weird characters. Why bother, I ask, if the effort to produce secure code is not that much?

Answer (score 5):

Like this:

```
procedure INSERT_BLOB_QUERY;
begin
  query.SQL.Text := 'INSERT INTO A_TABLE (BLOB_FIELD) VALUES (:VAL)';
  query.ParamByName('VAL').AsString := 'a blob string to be inserted';
end;
```

Your code doesn't work because you're not passing the string as a parameter, you're passing it as part of the query. If you do that, you obviously need to QUOTE it: the way you're doing it Interbase will try to interpret it as SQL commands, not as a literal string to be inserted in a db column.

None the less, don't go for quoting. It's always better to use parameters, it's safer!

Comment: one minor nitpick... `query.SQL` is a `TStringList`, and so you need to use `query.SQL.Text` instead. +1, though.